# I have a problem with a Makefile in the line 8

Tags: makefile, tabs

That is my problem:

```
j@j:~/workspace/emc$ make
Makefile:8: *** falta un separador.  Alto. (In english is: missing separator. Stop.)
j@j:~/workspace/emc$
```

I'm tried all of posible for a one solution, but i don't have nothing, this problem is very  disgusting

And this is my code:

```
exec = emc.out
sources = $(wildcard src/*.c)
objects = $(sources:.c=.o)
flags = -g


$(exec): $(objects)
    gcc $(objects) $(flags) -o $(exec)

%.o: %.c include/%.h
    gcc -c $(flags) $< -o $@

clean :
    -rm *.out
    -rm *.o
    -rm src/*.o
```

Comment: This is probably the single most common question about using `make`.  Any search of the error message `missing separator` will get you pages and pages of answers.